# ViewFlipper and display not First item onCreate

Tags: android, android-layout

You know if I set up a ViewFlipper in layout, it always start from the first item to bottom.

But is there a way to start from the 2nd or 3rd item of ViewFlipper on "onCreate"?

Let's say if counter == 2, the page will display <-- 2 --> item onCreate.

This is my onCreate and flipper.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);}
```

xml

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/flipin"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/flipout"    >      

    <!-- 1 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">            
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/airongbg"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <!-- 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/hopefalls"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <!-- 3 -->    
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/moon"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
    ((ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.flipper)).setDisplayedChild(1); //1 for 2 Since it accept Ordinal number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Get the position of the item which you want to show by

```
 int id ;
    id=flipper.indexOfChild(ImageView1);
```

//  then call the itm as

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(id);

you will be able to set the desired item
```